# How to consent to an Azure Active Directory Enterprise App for Multi-Tenant Login without Publisher Approval during development?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

How can I consent to from Active Directory A to an Azure Active Directory Enterprise App B on Subscription B for Multi-Tenant Login without Publisher approval during development?

I'm currently developing an app which should support login from multiple Microsoft hosted active directories under multiple domains. Thus I considered Azure Active Directory Enterprise Apps for multi-tenant.

My publisher and and publisher domain approval is still pending and taking long. Also I think Azure changed on 09.11.2020 what end users cannot consent to non-approved apps, however as I read this should not impact an admin consent.

Earlier I was able to add the enterprise app in azure app gallery by searching for the uuid.

However my azure enterprise app does not show up in any other azure tenant. What is necessary to find and consent to it from another active directory during development and for prototyping without publisher approval?

Thx I appreciate your expertise and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent).

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id-of-other-foreign-tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

with {tenant-id} being the foreign tenant which likes to approve the enterprise app and {client-id} being application id of enterprise app to approve.

Use an admin from other tenant to sign in to grant the admin consent.

Then the enterprise app will appear in that tenant.